# How to check if a filter has timed out?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, filters

According to the [JSON RPC docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_uninstallfilter), filters timeout when they aren't polled with `eth_getFilterChanges` for a period of time.

`eth_getFilterChanges(ID)` seems to return the same result `{"jsonrpc"=>"2.0", "id"=>1, "result"=>[]}` regardless of whether a filter with the supplied `ID` exists or not.

Thus, it seems that `eth_getFilterChanges` is ambiguous and we have no way of knowing whether the filter has timed out or if it simply doesn't contain  changes since the last poll.

I also checked the other filter related methods and didn't find any method that would allow to check the state (active or removed) of a filter.

How do we handle timeouts and what is the exact timeout period? How do we check the state of a filter? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Just checked.  In current Geth (v1.5.7), `eth_getFilterChanges` returns

- `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":168,"result":[]}` when there is no changes.
- `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":168,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"filter not found"}}` when filter id not exists e.g. after timeout

And according to source (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/ac93a6ff6cd1200ab0fb67a5bd0c02cb70646632/eth/filters/api.go) timeout is 5 minutes